# Android width according to another width

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

The following image can display the final result I want to get.

[image]

A: If I enter small values, the Image (which contains the rectangle) is fine.

B: If I enter large values, the Image instead of re-adjust, it stays with the same width.

C: Is the final result I want. The rectangle adjust himself to the lenght of the textview values.

I'd like to know if it's possible to  get that result only in XML? My current code is the following:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sendsuccess"
/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/numberId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/numberId"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
/>
```

Comment: I dont understand what your asking.

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: I've just edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

If the background you are using is just a simple rectangle, you can create that background image from xml and set it as your `TextView`'s background.

Create a folder called `drawable` in `res` folder. And inside that `drawable` folder create an xml file (shape) (lets call it `text_background.xml`)

text_background.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<!-- Rounded Corner Settings -->
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

<!-- Rectangle Solid Color Settings -->
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<!-- Rectangle Stroke Settings -->
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

And then in your `layout` xml add this shape to your `TextView` as `background`

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/numberId"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/numberId"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:background="@drawable/text_background"
/>
```

And remove the `ImageView` from the layout as you don't need it anymore.
Hope this helps

Comment: I think your solution is what I need. But how should I adapt the text_background.xml to receive instead of colors, an image?

Comment: If you want to use an image for background, you can use 9-patch as Damien R. said. You can find more info about 9-patch at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html and http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you want to do is to create a 9patch for your `TextView`. You need to set your 9patch as a background of your `TextView`. This wa, it will always fill with your `TextView` content.

Comment: I don't think I got it..can you provide some tutorial or example code?